# MYSQL query with array that comes from ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have an ''field_names' array that comes from ajax function. Its structure is simple.

```
Array ( [0] => balcony [1] => bathroom_count [2] => building_age [3] => exchangeable [4] => floor_count [5] => floor_location [6] => furnished [7] => heating_system [8] => inside_site [9] => room_count [10] => using_status [11] => available_for_loan [12] => )
```

I'm using that array for define my input values. But when i use that array for insert query, my code treats like there is no array even i already use it on my form.

```
$lastid = mysqli_insert_id($connect);
    foreach ($field_names as $field_name) {
                    $ads_field_query_string = "INSERT INTO ads_fields (ads_id, field_name, field_value) VALUES ('$lastid', '$field_name', '$_POST[$field_name]')";
                    $ads_fields_query_run = mysqli_query($connect, $ads_fields_query_string);
                    echo $ads_field_query_string;
                }
```

Comment: what should be your $_POST["field_name"]? is this your full code? where do you say that $field_names = $_POST["field_names"];? if you have that line, have you tried dumping it out via var_dump($_POST["field_names"]);?

Comment: I have 5 input for my fields.  Each one uses an element of this array as a name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a slight typo

Initially the sql query is declared as `$ads_field_query_string` but then in the call to `mysqli_query` you reference `$ads_fields_query_string`~ note the extra `s`

If you were to use simpler names this error would have been easier to spot, such as:

```
$lastid = mysqli_insert_id( $connect );

foreach ( $field_names as $field ) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `ads_fields` ( `ads_id`, `field_name`, `field_value` ) VALUES ( '$lastid', '$field', '{$_POST[$field]}' )";

    $res = mysqli_query( $connect, $sql );
    echo $sql;
}
```

That said, the code is vulnerable to SQL injection - it would be much better to use a prepared statement, like this perhaps:

```
$sql='insert into `ads_fields` ( `ads_id`, `field_name`, `field_value` ) values (?,?,?)';
$stmt=$connect->prepare( $sql );
if( $stmt ){
    $stmt->bind_param( 'iss', $lastid, $name, $value );

    foreach( $field_names as $name ){
        $value=$_POST[ $name ];
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $connect->close();
}
```

Comment: Copy/paste typo. Fixed. But still, query treats like there's no array.

Comment: Perhaps if you can add the ajax function it might help